# iPhone safari asks confirmation to submit form again when back button is pressed

Tags: iphone, forms, html, safari, mobile-website

I have a form. When I click on the submit button the form is submitted and result is loaded in  the next page. In this page I have a hyperlink. On click of that hyperlink, I am going to another page. At this point if I click 'Back' button of the browser, I get a confirmation whether I should submit the form or not. How do I disable this ? I am storing results in sessionStorage so I do not need to submit form again.

Comment: I think this is default Safari behavior and can't be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Use the PRG pattern, which can be described as:

```
Never show pages in response to POST
Always load pages using GET
Navigate from POST to GET using REDIRECT
```

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get and links from there